# SQL query keeps prompting: 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier"

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL query keeps prompting:

```
"ORA-00904: "DATE_FORMAT": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 11 Column: 110"
```

message while running query

```sql
select AUX4 as "ID",COUNT(AUX4) AS "Fails number" FROM audits where TRSTATUS <> 'SUCCESS' and DATECREATED > UPPER(DATE_FORMAT(NOW()-INTERVAL '7' DAY,"%d-%b-%y")) GROUP BY AUX4 ORDER by "Fails number" desc;
```

Works perfectly fine if date for comparison is entered manually as in

```sql
select AUX4,COUNT(AUX4) AS "Fails number" FROM audits where TRSTATUS <> 'SUCCESS' and DATECREATED > '25-NOV-2019' GROUP BY AUX4 ORDER by "Fails number" desc;
```

Comment: MySQL giving Oracle errors? Also why convert to strings when comparing dates?

Comment: This is ran on SQL developer. Might incorrectly selected the tags.  Had to change date format as it didn't match existing one in DB. That might have caused the problem?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Oracle owns MySQL :-)

Comment: Try using single quotes around the date mask, e.g. `'%d-%b-%y'` ... double quotes are used for database identifiers (e.g. column and table names)

Comment: @Tim, have tried that but unfortunately there is no luck. It seems that query doesn't file format change (according to the error). Tried to run the same without changing the format but then it doesn't match with date that is listed in DB.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, but that doesn’t magically change the errors MySQL throws to be Oracle error codes. This clearly isn’t MySQL.

Comment: This query is running in MySql Workbench...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is your oracle date formatting. replace your `mysql` `NOW()` to `sysdate`, replace `DATE_FORMAT` to `TO_CHAR`.

```
select AUX4 as "ID"
    ,COUNT(AUX4) AS "Fails number" 
FROM audits where TRSTATUS <> 'SUCCESS' and 
DATECREATED > UPPER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-INTERVAL '7' DAY,'DD-MON-YYYY')) 
GROUP BY AUX4 ORDER by "Fails number" desc;
```

This [link](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql-to-oracle/date_format#:~:targetText=DATE_FORMAT%20%2D%20Convert%20Date%20to%20String%20%2D%20MySQL%20to%20Oracle%20Migration,TO_CHAR%20use%20different%20format%20strings.) might help you convert your `mysql` queries to oracle.

Comment: Took ages to run the query but that gave required data. Sadly couldn't think of this solution myself. THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR QUICK RESOLUTION :)